# Is it possible to Pivot data like this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, pivot

I have data that looks as follows:

[image]

I would like to pivot this data so that there is only a single row for the SubId. The columns would be SubId, 802Lineage, 802ReadTime, 1000Lineage, 1000ReadTime etc.

If it wasn't for the requirement to have the Lineage included, this would be pretty straightforward, as follows:

```
Select SubId, [800] as [800Time], [1190] as [1190Time], [1605] as [1605Time]
From
(Select SubId, ProcessNumber, ReadTime From MyTable) as SourceTable
PIVOT
(
    Max(ReadTime)
    For ProcessNumber IN ([800],[802],[1190],[1605])
) as PivotTable;
```

I'm just not sure how to do this with the Lineage included. This is for SQL Server 2012

Comment: Why not join two pivots on SubId?

Comment: Can you produce an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pivot manually:

```
select
    SubId,
    max(case when ProcessNumber = 802 then ReadTime end) as [802Time],
    max(case when ProcessNumber = 802 then Lineage end) as [802Lineage],
    ....
from SourceTable
group by SubId
```

Comment: @RandyMinder this kind of pivot is very flexible, you can mix different aggregate, if you like. It does take a bit more code, but for me it's much easier to extend in the future than standard pivot

Answer (score 1):

Example of joining two pivot tables, as requested in comments.

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable (SubId int, ProcessNumber int, Lineage varchar(16), ReadTime datetime)
INSERT INTO #MyTable 
        (SubID, ProcessNumber, Lineage, ReadTime)
VALUES
        (1, 9, 'A', GETDATE()),
        (1, 8, 'A', GETDATE()),
        (1, 7, 'B', GETDATE()),
        (2, 9, 'C', GETDATE()),
        (2, 8, 'C', GETDATE())
SELECT * 
FROM (
   Select SubId, [9] as [9Time], [8] as [8Time], [7] as [7Time]
   From
   (Select SubId, ProcessNumber, ReadTime From #MyTable) as SourceTable
   PIVOT(Max(ReadTime) For ProcessNumber IN ([9],[8],[7],[6])) as PivotTable1
) AS T1
INNER JOIN (
   Select SubId, [9] as [9Lineage], [8] as [8Lineage], [7] as [7Lineage]
   From
   (Select SubId, ProcessNumber, Lineage From #MyTable) as SourceTable
   PIVOT(Max(Lineage) For ProcessNumber IN ([9],[8],[7],[6])) as PivotTable1
 ) AS T2
ON T1.SubId = T2.SubId
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PIVOT function to get the result but you will have to unpivot the `Lineage` and `ReadTime` columns from the multiple columns into multiple rows.

Since you are using SQL Server 2012 you can unpivot the data using CROSS APPLY with VALUES:

```
select subid, 
  colname = cast(processNumber as varchar(10)) + colname,
  value
from mytable
cross apply
(
  values
    ('Lineage', Lineage),
    ('ReadTime', convert(varchar(20), readtime, 120))
) c (colname, value)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/595af/8). This will convert your current data into the format:

```
|       SUBID |      COLNAME |               VALUE |
|-------------|--------------|---------------------|
| 12010231146 |   802Lineage |              PBG12A |
| 12010231146 |  802ReadTime | 2012-01-02 21:44:00 |
| 12010231146 |  1000Lineage |              PBG12A |
| 12010231146 | 1000ReadTime | 2012-01-02 21:43:00 |
| 12010231146 |  1190Lineage |              PBG11B |
| 12010231146 | 1190ReadTime | 2012-01-03 14:36:00 |
```

Once the data is in this format, then you can easily apply the PIVOT function to get your final result:

```
select *
from
(
  select subid, 
    colname = cast(processNumber as varchar(10)) + colname,
    value
  from mytable
  cross apply
  (
    values
      ('Lineage', Lineage),
      ('ReadTime', convert(varchar(20), readtime, 120))
  ) c (colname, value)
) d
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for colname in ([802Lineage], [802ReadTime],
                  [1000Lineage], [1000ReadTime],
                  [1190Lineage], [1190ReadTime])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/595af/2).

The above works great if you have a limited number of rows that you want to convert, but if you have an unknown number then you can use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(cast(processnumber as varchar(10))+col) 
                    from mytable
                    cross apply
                    (
                      select 'Lineage', 0 union all
                      select 'ReadTime', 1
                    ) c (col, so)
                    group by processnumber, col, so
                    order by processnumber, so
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT subid, ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
              select subid, 
                colname = cast(processNumber as varchar(10)) + colname,
                value
              from mytable
              cross apply
              (
                values
                  (''Lineage'', Lineage),
                  (''ReadTime'', convert(varchar(20), readtime, 120))
              ) c (colname, value)
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for colname in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/595af/7).  This gives a result:

```
|       SUBID | 802LINEAGE |         802READTIME | 1000LINEAGE |        1000READTIME | 1190LINEAGE |        1190READTIME | 1605LINEAGE |        1605READTIME | 1745LINEAGE |        1745READTIME | 1790LINEAGE |        1790READTIME | 1990LINEAGE |        1990READTIME | 2690LINEAGE |        2690READTIME | 2795LINEAGE |        2795READTIME | 2990LINEAGE |        2990READTIME | 3090LINEAGE |        3090READTIME | 3290LINEAGE |        3290READTIME |
|-------------|------------|---------------------|-------------|---------------------|-------------|---------------------|-------------|---------------------|-------------|---------------------|-------------|---------------------|-------------|---------------------|-------------|---------------------|-------------|---------------------|-------------|---------------------|-------------|---------------------|-------------|---------------------|
| 12010231146 |     PBG12A | 2012-01-02 21:44:00 |      PBG12A | 2012-01-02 21:43:00 |      PBG11B | 2012-01-03 14:36:00 |      PBG11B | 2012-01-03 15:15:00 |      PBG11A | 2012-01-03 15:16:00 |      PBG11A | 2012-01-03 15:19:00 |      PBG11A | 2012-01-03 15:23:00 |      PBG11A | 2012-01-03 15:32:00 |      PBG11A | 2012-01-03 15:39:00 |      PBG11A | 2012-01-03 15:41:00 |      PBG11A | 2012-01-03 15:46:00 |      PBG11A | 2012-01-03 15:47:00 |
```